# Angular typechecking using interface

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web, frontend

How to do a strict type checking in angular for the response returned.

1.data.json file for temp api purpose

```json
[
  {
    "name": "Someone 1",
    "comment": "comment 1",
    "line": "line 1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Someone 2",
    "comment": "comment 2",
    "line": "line 2"
  },
  {
    "name": 3,
    "comment": "comment 3",
    "line": "line 3"
  }
]
```

2. a model interface

```js
export interface Model {
  name: number;
  comment: string;
  line: string;
}
```

3.Service class app.service.ts

```js
export class AppService {
  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) {}

  private api = "../api/data.json";

  loadData(): Observable<Model[]> {
    return this._http.get<Model[]>(this.api);
    //.pipe(tap((data) => console.log("All:" + JSON.stringify(data))));
  }

  loadSingle(): Observable<Model> {
    return this.loadData().pipe(map((data: Model[]) => data[2]));
  }
}
```

4.component class app.component.ts

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  myvarArray: Model[];

  myvarSingleton: Model;

  constructor(private _appService: AppService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._appService.loadData().subscribe((data) => {
      this.myvarArray = data;
    });

    this._appService.loadSingle().subscribe((data) => {
      this.myvarSingleton = data;
      console.log(data.name + ":" + data.comment);
    });
  }
}
```

5.app.component.html

```html
<h1>Printing obj data</h1>
<ul *ngFor="let data of myvarArray">
  <li>{{ data.name }} -- {{ data.line }}</li>
</ul>

<h1>Printing Single data</h1>
<span>{{ myvarSingleton.name }}</span>
```

What would be a way to implement strict typechecking so that the values in the data.json conform to the types declared in the interface? **My point being though name is given as number when data returned to app.component it will still not show any error during compile time and if there is some way to type check this implicitly rather an explicit validation function?**

**[Edit]** Also why am i receiving undefined property on myvarSingleton.name error when clearly the property is defined in the interface (but data displays correctly on the page)? And why is it called 3 times?

[console shows error saying name is undefined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWVCL.png)

Comment: Typescript is a static type check feature. At run time JavaScript has no "strict" type checking. You would need to write the code to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: Hello! For future reference it makes life much easier for us to help out when you past the code in the question itself as opposed to screenshots.

Comment: Can you please add source code instead of images? It would be a great!

Comment: formatted the code

Answer (score 0):

You can not validate JSON.parse with TypeScript. You can only tell TS what your JSON is supposed to be. A work around is to create a validation function like this for example:

```
function isModel(arg: any): arg is Model {
  return arg 
  && (arg.name && typeof (arg.name) == 'string')
  && (arg && arg.comment && typeof (arg.comment) == 'string');
}
```

Notice that the type checking is hard coded. You might want to cast the JSON to a class instead of using an interface if it gives you more advantage.

Comment: I was thinking more in lines of interfaces saving from compile time errors .but i guess in case of json response there is no other way rather than writing an explicit validation function. _Thanks_